# \unit macro not working on the siunitx package

Tags: siunitx, undefined, units, control, sequence

I am trying to make use of the \unit macro that is described on page 6 of the [siunitx user manual](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) and the compiler tells me that I have an undefined control sequence.

```
\unit{\kilo\gram\metre\per\square\second}
```

I have added the siunitx package to the tex file, and other macros in the package such as \num and \ang work.

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works ok here. Are you sure you have installed the latest version and that you *do not* use the `units` package also?

Comment: I am using overleaf, and so i would assume that everything there is up to date, I do have alot of other packages installed however, but not units.

Comment: overleaf is not up-to-date, they use texlive 2020.

Comment: Overleaf is *not* updated to the last --- it's frozen on TeXLive 2020 now, so they have `siunitx` v2. Change `\unit{}` to `\si{}`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you have v2 available: I re-worked the document commands for v3. You could use the v2 command `\si`, or if you want your input to use the v3 interfaces, we can do a bit of work to set up `\unit`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ifdefined\unit\else
  \ifdefined\NewCommandCopy
    \NewCommandCopy\unit\si
  \else
    \NewDocumentCommand\unit{O{}m}{\si[#1]{#2}}
  \fi
\fi
\begin{document}
\unit{\kilo\gram\metre\per\square\second}
\end{document}
```

(This should work with any release of `siunitx` since v2.0: if you only have v1, life gets more interesting! But that would mean a pre-2009 LaTeX installation.)

Comment: I couldn't figure out why the same document worked on my PC but not on my Mac - the Mac Tex Live Utility had auto updated to v2. This solution worked and made the document portable! Thanks!