# Why I can't use \unit command in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, best-practices, undefined, units, unit-of-measure

Most of the time I work with [siunitx](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) package I need to specify only units like: "give the answer in psia".

For achieving this every time I try with `\unit{\watt}` (W for example) but it produces a **!Undefined control sequence**. I need to use `\SI{}{\watt}` but I'm afraid this it's not the proper way.

I use PDFLatex as compiler and my config is like this:

```latex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

%%%%%%%   Document configuration   %%%%%%%
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\decimalpoint
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%   Math   %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = fraction}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%    Custom units     %%%%%%%%%
\DeclareSIUnit\dolar{d\text{ó}lar}
\DeclareSIUnit\fahrenheit{\degree F}
\DeclareSIUnit\feet{ft}
\DeclareSIUnit\pound{lb}
\DeclareSIUnit\btu{BTU}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    I like to output Watt as \unit{\watt}
    
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: What version of `siunitx` is installed on your device? (You will usually find this in the build log.) According to section 5 in the corresponding manual, you need `siunitx` version 3 for the new macros to be available. Some more information is available in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601428/.

Comment: Thank you, I had updated the package a few days ago, but for some reason it failed. and looking at the.log you mentioned, I found out that I still had v2.8 I updated an it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have version 2, then `\unit` is not available and the older name is `\si`. As I've [mentioned in my blog](https://www.texdev.net/2021/06/30/siunitx-v2-to-v3), you can move to the newer interfaces *and* cover both v2 and v3 by ensuring that the newer names are available

```latex
\ifdefined\qty\else
  \ifdefined\NewCommandCopy
    \NewCommandCopy\qty\SI
  \else
    \NewDocumentCommand\qty{O{}mm}{\SI[#1]{#2}{#3}}
  \fi
\fi
\ifdefined\unit\else
  \ifdefined\NewCommandCopy
    \NewCommandCopy\unit\si
  \else
    \NewDocumentCommand\unit{O{}m}{\si[#1]{#2}}
  \fi
\fi
```